# How do you bring the thumb of a UISlider to the front of the track?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have sort of a strange problem that I'm stumped with at the moment.  I have a UISlider which has a custom thumb image that appears behind the slider track.

Here's the code that creates the slider:

```
- (UISlider *)sliderControl
{
    if (!_sliderControl)
    {
        _sliderControl = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
        
        // slider images
        [_sliderControl setThumbImage:[UIImage bm_imageWithBundlePath:BMVideoPlayerScrubberImageName] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [_sliderControl setMinimumTrackImage:[[UIImage alloc] init] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [_sliderControl setMaximumTrackImage:[[UIImage alloc] init] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [_sliderControl setAccessibilityIdentifier:kSliderPositionAccessibilityIndicator];
        
        // slider targets
        [_sliderControl addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        [_sliderControl addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderTouchStart:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

        // A little clang diagnostic 'hackerings' to silence the 'integer constant not in range of enumerated type' error
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wassign-enum"
        UIControlEvents controlEvents = (UIControlEventTouchUpInside|UIControlEventTouchUpOutside);
        [_sliderControl addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderTouchEnd:) forControlEvents:controlEvents];
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
    }
    
    return _sliderControl;
}
```

The problem, as you can see below, is that the thumb is behind the track.  So, it appears like the thumb is transparent as you can see the slider's track inside the circle.  Here's a picture from the view debugger:

[image]

I cannot figure out how to move the thumb so that it is on top of the track.  Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: A little confusing... your code shows you setting both track images to empty images, so the track shouldn't even be visible. Since this is part of a custom class, edit your question and include the full class code.

Comment: the use of this #pragma indicates your interface declaration for use of UIKit is not working as it should otherwise such warning would not appear, no need to silence this. There is something else wrong but not directly in the shown code. I could not reproduce your bug with the code above. Also the view debugger shown from behind must show the thumbnail in the way its in your pic.